# NWJS - "Refused to display ... in a frame" error

Tags: same-origin-policy, nwjs

I am attempting to display a webpage from a device on my local network in an iframe.  However I get:

`"Refused to display 'http://192.168.1.252/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.", source: chrome-error://chromewebdata/ (1)`

I have followed the documentation regarding setting up node frames https://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Security%20in%20NW.js/

My manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "AppApp",
  "description": "AppApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "icon": "icons/app.icns",
  "main": "html/main.html",
  "chromium-args": "--enable-logging=stderr --enable-spell-checking",
  "window": {
    "toolbar": false,
    "width": 800,
    "height": 500
  },
  "nodejs": true,
  "node-remote": "*://*"
}
```

iframe HTML:

```
<iframe src="http://192.168.1.252/"></iframe>
```

Is there more that I need to do to bypass the same origin policy?

Comment: Whatever web application or site is being served from `http://192.168.1.252/` does not want its content in a frame. Do you control that application? If so, change or remove its [X-Frame-Options header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: @Phil I have no control over the application from the device. Point is, according to this: https://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Security%20in%20NW.js/, a node frame should be able to "Bypass all security restrictions, such as sandboxing, same origin policy etc."  Isn't that what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: I've also tried adding --disable-web-security to chromium-args.

Comment: Unrelated, but never use `*://*` for node-remote. That means that if by some means a page from the internet runs in NW.js, it will have full access to the computer, to read/write/delete your files, download and run virus.exe, track every keystroke, etc. Major security risk. Instead only give node access to trusted urls, like `"node-remote": "http://192.168.1.252"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, and a workaround is provided here:

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/7049

"The X-Frame-Options workaround should be used in an iframe with the nwfaketop property."

According to the bug, if `X-Frame-Options: Deny` there isn't a problem, it is only if `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin` when the problem exists, and the
`nwfaketop` workaround must be used.

(Note, I observed that using --disable-web-security in chromium-args caused the page to not load properly, so I removed it.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't *---disable-web-security*, but do this instead:

**Step 1:** Save the script below as **background.js** and move this file to your project's folder...

```
// Removes x-frame-options and content-security-policy headers

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(info){

 var H=info.responseHeaders, N='';

  for(let i=H.length-1; i>=0; i--){

   N=H[i].name.toLowerCase();

   if((N.includes('x-frame-options'))||(N.includes('content-security-policy'))||(N.includes('report-'))){

    H.splice(i,1);

}} return {responseHeaders:H};},{urls:['<all_urls>'],types:['main_frame','sub_frame']},['blocking','responseHeaders','extraHeaders']);
```

**Step 2:** In your **manifest.json** ensure you correctly accommodate this line...

```
 "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"],"persistent": true},
```

**Step 3:** In your **manifest.json** ensure you include **"webRequest"** among the other Chrome APIs etc...

```
"permissions": ["<all_urls>","webRequest", .......
```

**Step 4:** Now compile your app, reload the offending site and have the last laugh! :)